# Fixing wrong charset on Google's Speech-to-text API response

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, google-speech-api

I am setting up a barebones Speech-to-text app in romanian, and the return file does not recognize special characters.

After running the command

`$ gcloud ml speech recognize ./foo.wav --language-code='ro-RO' > foo.txt`

Opening the file in a text editor shows

"folose\u0219ti cuvintele tale s\u0103 vorbim cu virgul\u0103 \u0219i cu puncte"

whereas the expected output is:

"folosești cuvintele tale să vorbim cu virgulă și cu puncte"

I have attempted several conversions with iconv, with no success whatsoever, along the lines of:

```
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 foo.txt > foo2.txt
$ iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 foo.txt > foo2.txt
```

Nothing I can think of (which is admittedly little) seems to work. Is there any way to have an editor display those characters without building an entire script to parse the text and place them where needed?